# Density parameter (cosmology) as a function of redshift

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology

Hopefully I'm missing some very basic algebra for this question. In essence, I need to derive the following:

$$
\Omega=\Omega_{1}\frac{(1+z)}{1+\Omega_1{z}}
$$
Now, I proceeded from the Friedmann equations as follows for a matter dominated Universe (and for $\Lambda=0$ and $k\neq{0}$):
$$
\frac{H^{2}}{H_{0}}=\Omega_{m}a^{-3}+\Omega_{\kappa}a^{-2}
$$
Knowing that $a=1/(1+z)$ I can re-arrange this to:
$$
\frac{H^{2}}{H_{0}}=\Omega_m(1+z)(1+z)^2+\Omega_{\kappa}(1+z)^2
$$
$$
\frac{H^{2}}{H_{0}}=(\Omega_m+\Omega_mz)(1+z)^2+\Omega_{\kappa}(1+z)^2
$$
Introducing the fact that $1-\Omega_{m}=\Omega_{\kappa}$:
$$
\frac{H^{2}}{H_{0}}=(\Omega_m+\Omega_{\kappa}+\Omega_mz)(1+z)^2=(1+\Omega_mz)(1+z)^2
$$
This is where I feel I am almost there but I've stumbled a little as to my next options. Any tips or advice would be brilliant!

Comment: Well for starters you need to introduce $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega$ in there with some other equation(s).

Comment: I assume by $\Omega_1$ you actually mean $\Omega_m$ (i.e. $\Omega_0$). You have derived how the Hubble parameter evolves. Now you need to use this to find how the density parameter evolves. THe density parameter is defined as $\Omega \equiv \rho/(3M_{\mathrm{pl}}^2H^2)$.

Comment: @darthplageuis how did u to ^2/_0=Ω^−3+Ω^−2 in the first place. Can u please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it. The last step is
$$
\Omega = \frac{\rho}{\rho_\text{c}} = \frac{\rho_0\,a^{-3}}{\rho_\text{c,0}}\frac{\rho_\text{c,0}}{\rho_\text{c}} = \Omega_m\,(1+z)^3\frac{H_0^2}{H^2},
$$
where we used the critical density
$$
\rho_\text{c} = \frac{3H^2}{8\pi G},\qquad \rho_\text{c,0} = \frac{3H_0^2}{8\pi G}.
$$
The result follows immediately from what you already derived.